# Which Windows SDK to use to build extensions for Python 3.5?

Tags: python, winapi, visual-studio-2015, python-3.5

Python 3.5 for Windows is [built with Visual Studio 2015](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html#compiling-python-on-windows):

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, which is the compiler used to build the official Python releases

Which version of the Windows SDK should you use to build extensions for Python 3.5? Presumably it's whichever ships with Visual Studio 2015, but which is that? I need to know precisely for https://github.com/pypa/python-packaging-user-guide/pull/172

On my computer I have several in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows`:

```
v6.0A
v7.0A
v7.1A
v8.0
v8.0A
v8.1
v8.1A
v10.0A
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Nope. In the end I rewrote my `appveyor.yml` following https://github.com/ogrisel/python-appveyor-demo/blob/master/appveyor.yml which doesn't need you to state the Windows SDK version explicitly

Answer (score 0):

On Python 3.5 and above, the environment does not need to be specifically configured, as is the case with 32-bit builds.